# No visuals under the plots view

Tags: r

Hi i am still a beginner in R. I need a minor assistance
R does not display plots. The plot view remain just blank after running the commands to draw plot.
Everything under the Plots options is not working. I have restarted the session, closed and started R. but no change.

I was working with the packages `ggplot2`, `tidyverse` and `dplyr`.

I don't recall uninstalling something

What could the problem be?

Comment: Is that in RStudio?

Comment: Can you show the command(s)?  Any error messages?